# What is the best way to auto-generate PBIs in TFS?

Tags: tfs, automation

I am looking for advice.

I have a requirement to generate 5 PBIs under a Feature.  We need the user to be able to trigger the process by populating a field for example.

Do I need code for this or is there a codeless method?

I can see that I can build Plugins for TFS.  I saw an example or two (although they were related to code check-ins).  I would be looking to investigate a trigger around the save of a feature and if a specific thing has occurred generate some child PBIs.

Ideally I would like a codeless method within TFS for this but am happy with investigating a Plugin if necessary.

We are on premise now but may move to online in six months or more.

Answer (score 0):

If you`ll move to online, you have several options and they are not codeless:

1. Use existing solutions, example: [TFS Aggregator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GiulioVian.TFSAggregator)
2. Create a custom web service to listen events and do some actions: [Web Hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops)
3. Create a custom application and use it as scheduled task: [Automation of state changing for Azure DevOps work items](https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/02/19/automation-of-state-changing-for-azure-devops-work-items-based-on-states-of-child-work-items/)